# Crashes of built-in apps in iOS 9

Tags: iphone, crash, ios

I've been having some problems on my iPhone 5 with the latest iOS 9 beta version: Music app and App Store app crashes —the latter while attempting to open any app page— and iTunes refuses to sync apps.

I don't remember when the problem began. It may have began after changing region, but I don't believe so.

P.S.
I tried to check my iOS 9 beta version but the about section on Settings crashes.

Comment: Remember to [report these bugs in the iOS 9 Beta to Apple](http://www.imore.com/how-send-apple-feedback-ios-9-public-beta)!

Answer (score 4):

Really, like with all beta software, bugs are to be encountered in the iOS 9 Beta. In fact, that's the point of betas, let certain users find and report bugs so that Apple, or whatever developer, can fix them before the software reaches mainstream adoption. So, unfortunately, all you can really do is report those bugs to Apple, using Feedback Assistant, then either wait for the public release of iOS 9 next month or downgrade to iOS 8.4.1.

Comment: That's what beta means: not quite ready for the public. If you can't stand bugs, stay out of it.

Comment: Report, reboot, report, reset.  Beta is beta.